# Unable to Connect to WCF Service from MVC Site

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, windows-services

I've written a WCF service that is hosted within a Windows Service on my home computer. I then wrote an MVC3 site that is attempting to connect to the service. The MVC3 site is hosted on godaddy servers. I opened the ports on my firewall correctly because I am able to access the service description site from a computer on a different network, and I even had a friend connect to the web service from a console app running on his computer, and it worked perfectly. However, when I attempt to call the web service from my MVC3 site it throws the following error:

There was no endpoint listening at http://myExternIpAddress:8000/MyService/service that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Here is the important part of the app.config for the service:

```
<services>
          <service  name="MyService.MyService"
                    behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" >
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/MyService/service" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>              
            <endpoint address="" 
                      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                      contract="MyService.IMyService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" 
                      binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />

          </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
```

and here is the service section of the web.config for the MVC3 site

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://myExternalIpAddress:8000/MyService/service"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"
        contract="LocalService.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks for any help that you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would contact GoDaddy for support. If the WCF service works from your friends machine - it is likely a hosting environment issue.